# How to let nodemailer receive emails only?

Tags: nodemailer

I'm using https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer, want to the server receive emails only, I don't want it have the ability to send emails out. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Setup a firewall rule for the outgoing SMTP port.

Comment: I can't find an attribute to set it.